# How would you define a function or script within your path that takes arguments to name the file?

Tags: files, alias

I am learning about the alias command in an online class. I am also interested in ffmpeg. I figured what if I typed an alias, then I wouldn't have to do all of that typing and remember the commands. This is what I did:

```
alias record="ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -r 15 -s $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -s 1440x900 -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 home/brian/test.avi"
```

And it worked with one problem. I can only make one file with this alias. I thought maybe the \ at the end in place of the output file would make a difference, but that didn't work either. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would do a timestamp like this (then your file name would always be unique):

```
alias record="ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -r 15 -s $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -s 1440x900 -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 /home/brian/test$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).avi"
```

That would be YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond